# Ajax, Jsp. radio button cannot set according to the return value, Return value is correct

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Ajax, Jsp. radio button cannot set according to the return value, Return value is correct

```
 if(value.UsrMasGender === 'Male'){
    $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Male"]').prop('checked', true); // #rdGender is my rb name 
 }else{
   $('#rdGender').find(':radio[name=rdGender][value="Fe-Male"]').prop('checked', true);  
 }
```